# PyQt6: Should I use QThread, or an alternative to multi-threading for GET requests and saving files from the internet?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6

I'm creating a GUI for downloading files off of the internet, right now I'm thinking of using `QThread` for the GET requests to get the files, and to save them to disk. Is this doable with [alternatives to threads](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/thread-basics.html#when-to-use-alternatives-to-threads)? I'd like to avoid using multi-threading if possible.

Comment: Yes, use QNetworkAccessManager for network requests

Comment: OP, were you able to figure this out? I'm doing something similar using requests, but want to use QThread

Comment: @TheCrazySwede, as mugiseyebrows said, `QNetworkManager` has been working great for handing network requests. It is asynchronous, in that the program doesn't block waiting for a response, so haven't had to use multithreading either.